# Acronyms in formal writing

Tags: word-choice, acronyms

I'm writing a formal essay, in which I use the acronym "US" a lot. Is this acceptable or should I write "United States" instead?

Comment: There is no definitive way to know whether "a lot" is "acceptable" or not; either condition is dependent on context and subject to opinion. At best, this is a request for writing advice, which is explicitly off-topic here. I suggest you start by choosing a [style guide](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/2579/16052) or finding a good editor, and following their advice on the treatment of abbreviations (and in English, *US* referring to *United States* is always an initialism, not an acronym).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether you should use initialisms at all is a matter of how strictly formal your formal paper is supposed to be. But even supposing that certain initialisms are acceptable, it is worth noting that some style guides assess the acceptability of *U.S.* as a noun and of *U.S.* as an adjective differently.

Here is the advice of *The Chicago Manual of Style*, fifteenth edition (2003):

> **15.34** *"U.S." or "US."* Except in scientific style, *U.S.* traditionally appears with periods. Periods may nonetheless be omitted in most contexts. Writers and editors need to weigh tradition against consistency. In running text, the abbreviation (in either form) is permissible when used as an adjective, but *United States* as a noun should be spelled out.

This guideline is, of course, only one style manual's opinion, but *Chicago* carries a lot of weight in U.S. publishing circles.

Comment: 'Should' implies 'appraising authority' implies 'opinion based' implies 'off-topic'.